# C language: try to implement IndexOf function

Tags: c, indexof

I try to learn `C Language` and something is not clear to me.
I want to write `IndexOf` function that search for char inside `string` and return the `Index` number.
I am running this under `ubuntu` and compile using this:

```
test1: test.c
    gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic test.c -o myprog1
```

This is what i have try:

```
int c;
int result;

    printf("Please enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);

    printf("Please enter char: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    result = indexof(str1, c);
    printf("Result value: %d\n", result);
```

And this is my function:

```
int indexof(char *str, int c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == c)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

So my problem is that my function return `-1` all the time

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that `Makefile` you show us is flawed. You have the target `test1` but the compilation creates the program `myprog1`. The program and target names should be the same.

Comment: if you type a character, `scanf("%d", &c);` is failed.

Comment: test1 is my test1.c

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/BJyY0W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%c",&c)`..you are getting input a character.

Working copy would besomethign like:-

```
char c; // you want to find the character not some integer. 
int result;

printf("Please enter string: ");
scanf("%s", str1);

printf("Please enter char: ");
scanf("%d", &c);

result = indexof(str1, c);
printf("Result value: %d\n", result);
```

#### Working example:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 int indexof(char *str, char c)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == c)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

int main()
{
    char c;
    int result;
    char str1[100];

        printf("Please enter string: ");
        scanf("%s", str1);

        printf("Please enter char: ");
        scanf(" %c", &c);

        result = indexof(str1, c);
        printf("Result value: %d\n", result);

}
```

Comment: But c is declare as int

Comment: I need to declare char or int ?  what is the best/right way ?

Comment: If declaring `c` as int is compulsory you can use my solution if char than this is right

Comment: i cannot read the char from the user, after read the first string this print Please enter char: Result value: -1

Comment: @user979033.: You don't need the `getchar()`..just remove the line.

Comment: same result, after read the string this print the result and not ask for char

Comment: You are doing something wrong..@user979033 First write the string+ press enter +write the character.+press the enter

Comment: This ask me Please enter string: and i type string and hit enter, after the this print Please enter char: Result value: -1

Comment: Have you copied the code from here?...do it again..copy it

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &c);` : `' '` can not be searched.

Comment: Ok that strange, i could swear that it was the same code... working now..

Comment: Ok what this is for: " %c" --> why i need this empty space before %c ?

Comment: @user979033.: Next `scanf` for reading the character just reads/consumes the newline and hence never waits for user input. I have used the ` ` in scanf to do that

Comment: @user979033.: When you enter the string and hit the ENTER key, a string and a character are placed in the input buffer, they are namely: the entered string and the newline character.The string gets consumed by the scanf but the newline remains in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `c` is int:

```
int indexof(char *str, int c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i]-'0') == c) // convert char to int
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> write IndexOf function that search for char inside string and return the Index number.

You might like to have a look at the [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) function, which can be used as shown below:

```
/* Looks up c in s and  return the 0 based index */
/* or (size_t) -1 on error of if c is not found. */

#include <string.h> /* for strchr() */
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

size_t index_of(const char * s, char c)
{
  size_t result = (size_t) -1; /* Be pessimistic. */

  if (NULL == s)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    char * pc = strchr(s, c);

    if (NULL != pc)
    {
      result = pc - s;
    }
    else
    {
      errno = 0;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
size_t index_of(const char *, char);

#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_xxx macros */
#include <stdio.h> /* for fprintf(), perror() */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno */

int main(void)
{
  result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  char s[] = "hello, world!";
  char c = 'w';

  size_t index = index_of(s, 'w');
  if ((size_t) -1) == index)
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (0 == errno) 
    {
      fprintf("Character '%c' not found in '%s'.\n", c, s);  
    }
    else
    {
      perror("index_of() failed");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf("Character '%c' is at index %zu in '%s'.\n", c, index, s);  
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: `<>` is invalid in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: fixed :}